# How to match the original message and its reply in the same thread using headers?

Tags: email, email-headers

When a mail is sent, there are headers that are sent along and one among that is the Message-Id and this is something that we save and when sending a a mail from the application as a response to that mail, we used the Message-Id that we had and set in the mail headers and following are the headers to which we added the previous email's Message-Id

1. Message-Id
2. References
3. In-Reply-To

And still, the mail response that was sent started a different email thread and didn't show in the same previous email thread. So what else should be considered to make the mails continue in the same thread.

Comment: Yeah so you want to rebuild Gmail / Outlook.com's "thread view". That's too broad of a question.

Comment: @CodeCaster Not really looking to rebuild but trying to know how the mails can be sent so as to make it look like a response to the previous message.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, nothing else should be necessary. You may want to check if the mail received by Outlook does contain the correct (and valid) header lines. Also you may want to check if the mail sent by your mail client contains these correct header lines.

Outlook is a Microsoft product, so it is probably malfunctioning? In [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/missing-header-fields-in-reply-to-references-for/18e73633-f98d-43de-b8f8-ff75b04073aa) (really hard to read) thread, someone encountered the problem, that the Outlook app on his mobile simply did not set the header lines. The *solution* (almost at last) is hilarious.